# Query related to hierarchy order and indented space

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

**Input Table** : Regions

```
    +---------------+---------------+---------- +-----------+
    | Child         | Parent        | Level     |  levelname|
    +---------------+---------------+---------- +-----------+
    | All Region    | All Region    | 1         |  national |
    | Africa Region | All Region    | 2         |   region  |
    | America       | All Region    | 2         |   region  |
    | Asia          | All Region    | 2         |   region  |
    | Europe Region | All Region    | 2         |   region  |
    | Africa        | Africa Region | 3         | Subregion |
    | Asia Pacific  | Asia          | 3         | Subregion |
    | Europe        | Europe Region | 3         | Subregion |
    | North America | America       | 3         | Subregion |
    | South America | America       | 3         | Subregion | 
    | Argentina     | South America | 4         |   Country |
    | Australia     | Asia Pacific  | 4         |   Country |
    | Pakistan      | Asia Pacific  | 4         |   Country | 
    | South Africa  | Africa        | 4         |   Country |
    | Tunisia       | Africa        | 4         |   Country | 
    | Uruguay       | South America | 4         |   Country |
    +-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here , regions are of 4 levels

- All region
- Region
- Sub Region
- Country

. The output should be as follows:

```
National
   Region_1
     SubRegion_1_1
       Country_1_1_1
       Country_1_1_2
    SubRegion_1_2
       Country_1_2_1
       Country_1_2_2
       Country_1_2_3
       Country_1_2_4
   Region_2
            …. And so on.
```

The output has some indented spaces to show visual effects,I dont know how to start the query.

Comment: search for `recursive cte`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need recursive cte to get data in hierarchy,

```
-- populate test data
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (Child VARCHAR(100), Parent VARCHAR(100), Level INT, LevelName VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
    ('AllRegion'        ,'AllRegion'        ,1      ,'national')
    ,('AfricaRegion'    ,'AllRegion'        ,2      ,'region')
    ,('America'         ,'AllRegion'        ,2      ,'region')
    ,('Asia'            ,'AllRegion'        ,2      ,'region')
    ,('EuropeRegion'    ,'AllRegion'        ,2      ,'region')
    ,('Africa'          ,'AfricaRegion'     ,3      ,'Subregion')
    ,('AsiaPacific'     ,'Asia'             ,3      ,'Subregion')
    ,('Europe'          ,'EuropeRegion'     ,3      ,'Subregion')
    ,('NorthAmerica'    ,'America'          ,3      ,'Subregion')
    ,('SouthAmerica'    ,'America'          ,3      ,'Subregion')
    ,('Argentina'       ,'SouthAmerica'     ,4      ,'Country')
    ,('Australia'       ,'AsiaPacific'      ,4      ,'Country')
    ,('Pakistan'        ,'AsiaPacific'      ,4      ,'Country')
    ,('SouthAfrica'     ,'Africa'           ,4      ,'Country')
    ,('Tunisia'         ,'Africa'           ,4      ,'Country')
    ,('Uruguay'         ,'SouthAmerica'     ,4      ,'Country')


-- use this query
;WITH Cte AS
(
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.LevelName, t.Parent ORDER BY t.Level) AS RowNo   -- assing a number to use for sorting 
    from @tbl t
),
Final AS
(
    SELECT t.child, t.Parent, t.Level
        ,CAST(RowNo AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS SortBy      -- this will be used for sorting.
    FROM Cte t
    WHERE t.level = 1

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT c.child, c.parent, c.level
        ,CAST(p.SortBy + CAST(c.RowNo AS VARCHAR(MAX))AS VARCHAR(MAX))  AS SortBy       -- keep adding the levels to the sort order
    FROM Cte c
    INNER JOIN Final p On c.Parent = p.child 
        AND c.Level > 1 -- this is required as the top parent is not set as NULL
)
SELECT Child
    ,SortBy
    ,SPACE(Level * 4 ) + Child AS HierarcyText
FROM Final
ORDER BY SortBy
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Hope this helps you.

### result :

```
Child             SortBy    HierarcyText               
----------------- ------- -----------------------------
AllRegion         1           AllRegion
AfricaRegion      11              AfricaRegion
Africa            111                 Africa
SouthAfrica       1111                    SouthAfrica
Tunisia           1112                    Tunisia
America           12              America
NorthAmerica      121                 NorthAmerica
SouthAmerica      122                 SouthAmerica
Uruguay           1221                    Uruguay
Argentina         1222                    Argentina
Asia              13              Asia
AsiaPacific       131                 AsiaPacific
Australia         1311                    Australia
Pakistan          1312                    Pakistan
EuropeRegion      14              EuropeRegion
Europe            141                 Europe
```

Answer (score 1):

A [SQL recursive CTE query](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-server-recursive-query-with-recursive-cte.aspx) can help to define hierarchy structures in SQL Server

Here is how you can use recursive query in SQL

```
;with cte as (
    select 
        Child, Parent, Level, LevelName, 
        rn = CONVERT(nvarchar(max), ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By Level Order By Child) )
    from Regions where Level = 1
    union all
    select
        r.Child, r.Parent, r.Level, r.LevelName, 
        rn = rn + '_' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max), ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By r.Level Order By r.Child) )
    from Regions r
    inner join cte 
        on  r.Level = (cte.Level + 1) and
            r.Parent = cte.Child
)
select * 
from cte
order by rn
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    case when ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY r2.levelname DESC) = 1 then r1.levelname else '' end as L1,  
    case when ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY r2.Child ORDER BY r2.Child DESC) = 1 then r2.Child else '' end as L2, 
    case when ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY r3.Child ORDER BY r3.Child DESC) = 1 then r3.Child else '' end as L3, 
    case when ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY r4.Child ORDER BY r4.Child DESC) = 1 then r4.Child  else '' end as L4
from #Regions r1
    inner join #Regions r2 on r1.Child = r2.Parent and r2.level = 2
    inner join #Regions r3 on r2.Child = r3.Parent and r3.level = 3
    inner join #Regions r4 on r3.Child = r4.Parent and r4.level = 4
where r1.level = 1
order by r1.levelname, r2.Child, r3.Child, r4.Child
```

1. Save below results to temp table
2. Add to all non-empty values tabs (CHAR(9)), CRLF  (CHAR(13) + CHAR(10))
3. Combine everything into one string
4. Print the string

I've done only step (1), steps (2)-(4) are easy. Let me know if still unclear.